# React Native: How to take ScreenShot Programmatically and save it to the gallery

Tags: react-native

I am not able to find any documents that explain this feature.

I would like to know how to take screenshot programmatically and save it to the gallery.

I tried the `react-native-view-show` gallery but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated

Current Code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, Image, ScrollView, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { captureScreen } from "react-native-view-shot";
import CameraRollExtended from "react-native-store-photos-album";

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true, "none");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Click"
          onPress={() => {
            captureScreen({
              format: "jpg",
              quality: 0.8
            }).then(
              uri => {
                CameraRollExtended.saveToCameraRoll(
                  {
                    uri: uri,
                    album: "Name"
                  },
                  "photo"
                );
              },
              error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-shot have you tried this ?

Comment: Yeah , It doesn't work

Comment: after capturing screnn shot you have to use camera roll to save its url  have you tried this also ?

Comment: Yes i tried that with a package . Check my updated code

Comment: Try using CameraRoll. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html